# how to get kafka to consume http streaming data on spring xd runtime?

Tags: spring, spring-xd, http-streaming, apache-kafka

Is it possible to have kafka source module work as a processor module in spring xd runtime? Any code samples?

I am trying to achieve something like this: http (xd source) | kafka source (xd processor)| kafka consumer (xd sink)

I am trying to do this because I have streaming data coming over http which I want to manage with kafka message bus.

My stream definition is this:

```
stream create kafkaSourceTest --definition "http --outputType=application/json | kafka --zkconnect=localhost:2181 --topic=kafkaTestTopic | log " --deploy
```

Putting out of the box implementation of kafka source module implementation in processor module of spring xd results in an error like this:

```
2015-05-12 11:18:52,914 1.1.1.RELEASE ERROR pool-13-thread-4 http.NettyHttpInboundChannelAdapter - Error sending message
```

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'admin:default,admin,singlenode,hsqldbServer:9393.kafkaSourceTest.0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to do this because I have streaming data coming over http which I want to manage with kafka message bus.

If you use kafka as the messagebus (after setting transport), then the stream like "http | log" will have the http messages flow through kafka messagebus. In this case, the topic in Kafka broker would be defined by XD internals.

> Is it possible to have kafka source module work as a processor module in spring xd runtime?

No, a source module can not act as a processor module. If you want the messages flow through specific topic in Kafka then you could have a stream that has a kafka sink module that receives data from http source and another stream that configures the kafka source module with the *same* topic.

and, this can be achieved this way:

stream create KafkaSink --definition "http --outputType=application/json | kafka --brokerList= --topic=kafkaTestTopic" --deploy

stream create KafkaSource --definition "kafka --zkconnect=localhost:2181 --topic=kafkaTestTopic | log" --deploy